# Difference between Inheriting the UINavigationController class and assigning the rootViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

What is the difference between inheriting the `UINavigationController` class and assigning the `rootViewController` property (or using `initWithRootViewController:` method)??

I am bit confuse about this. Consider below code inheritance of UINavigationController :

```
@interface NativeViewController : UINavigationController
{

}
```

Now consider below code using initWithRootViewController: method:

```
UINavigationController *viewController = nil;
if (self) {
    NativeViewController *vc = [[NativeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NativeViewController" bundle:nil];
    viewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [vc autorelease];
}
return viewController;
```

When to use Inheritance like the first case and when to use `initWithRootViewController:` Method??

What will happen to `rootViewController` property in case of inheritance??

Same question is for `UITabbarController` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass the container (UINavigationController, UITabBarController) only in situations where you need control over the container's functionality or appearance that isn't provided by UIAppearance or delegate methods.

In all other cases (which will be the majority), you'd set the root view controller or viewControllers properties. You don't need to subclass to provide basic functionality. These are *containers* - most of your UI comes from the child view controllers.

Comment: As such we are able to customize all the properties of Navigation Controller or TabBarController when we are NOT inheriting... like customize NavigationBar by accessing **self.navigationController** property. Currently, i cannot see the explicit use of subclassing this two classes. Can you please provide such usecase where i MUST need subclassing?? Reason behind this is, I have issues in my project where subclassing is not working and if I set rootViewController then it works... so i need proper reason when will i need subclassing navigationController.

Comment: Well, you'd almost never need to do it. Perhaps if you wanted to change the animation when view controllers are pushed or popped, or something like that. Setting the root view controller is nothing to do with subclassing - even a subclass will need a root view controller, or to have the viewControllers array set.

Answer (score 2):

First one is for customizing `UINavigationController`.
In other hands, second one is for initializing the `UINavigationController` with very first viewcontroller in it.
Let say, `UINavigationController` itself is just placeholder for navigating `UIViewController`s.

You still should put `rootViewController` in case of inheritance of `UINavigationController`.

Comment: What will happen if i dont put rootViewController??? What is exact purpose of rootViewController?

Comment: As I said, UINavigationController is just placeholder. So you would see nothing inside it when you don't set rootViewController. And it has rootViewController so that you can get back to rootViewController whenever you need.

Comment: If I place a label on UINavigationController View and will push other ViewController in NavigationController then I will see the Label in that new ViewController. Reason is I have put UILabel in NavigationController's view and not rootViewController's view. So my question is in which EXPLICIT case i will need subclassing the UINavigationController??

Comment: Let say, you need several UINavigationControllers and they have the same UI/functionality in all of them. You should place the same code here and there and this is obviously not professional to code and manage them. Furthermore, you can need the same thing on future projects. You can do INHERIT UINavigationController in such cases.